# spring data 2 difference between findById vs getOne

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

After upgrading my web application from spring boot 1.5.10 to spring boot 2.0.0 I ran into some runtime exceptions when accessing single entities.

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session

My Repository:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

In one of my services I called in spring data 1.x `myRepository.findOne(id);` to fetch a single entity. But the method findOne(Long id) was removed in spring data 2 so I had to switch to another method.

I found `JpaRepository#getOne(ID id);` After switching `findOne` to `getOne` all tests passed and were green. But during runtime I received the above mentioned exception. `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`

So I searched again for suitable methods and found `CrudRepository#findById(ID id)`

This time all worked out and I am happy, **but the question is now, why do I get the `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` when using `getOne()` ?**

Comment: you get **org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException** due the fact that you try to access entity fields after session termination

Comment: @gstackoverflow Where is the transaction boundary? I don't see it in the logs

Comment: @gstackoverflow What is the actual difference between the two. My understanding is that getOne returns a proxy, does findById not do that? Is the actual instance of the object returned populated with all the values? What happened to the findOne method?